# Dashboard Hyperlink or Iframe URL: Filter Parameter Required

Tags: dashboard, jasperserver

I have a dashboard made up of several dashlets (based on ad hoc views) and some filters.

I have set up a hyperlink on one dashlet that allows the user to click on a product and drill to another report.

The hyperlink needed to pass the Product in the Dashlet that the user clicks on as well as any selections made on the filters within the dashboard, for example filter the dashboard on certain Supplier Types.

I got this working using the following syntax: -

```
repo:/reportPath?$P{"p_SupplierType=",Supplier_Type_Filter , ? "&"}&p_Product=$P{Product Field}
```

This works fine.

THE PROBLEM

The issue is that if I don't select anything in my Supplier Type filter (i.e I want all Supplier Types) then I get an error telling me that Value for parameter 'Supplier_Type_Filter' is not set.

Anybody had the same or similar issues and have a solution or a workaround or even just an idea?

Thanks in advance.